Error during pipeline execution with SimpleKGPipeline: "Input should be a valid string"
I'm trying to execute a knowledge graph pipeline using the Anthropics LLM in combination with SimpleKGPipeline. However, I’m encountering an error during the execution of the run_async method.
Here is the error message:
ERROR - Error during pipeline execution: 1 validation error for LLMResponse  
content  
Input should be a valid string [type=string_type, input_value=[TextBlock(text='{\n  "no...\n  ]\n}', type='text')], input_type=list]  
For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.9/v/string_type  

Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "\Local\Temp\ipykernel_28080\1943368097.py", line 138, in define_and_run_pipeline  
response = await kg_builder.run_async(text=text)  


It seems the pipeline expects a string, but the response being passed is a list instead. Here's the relevant code snippet where the error occurs:
response = await kg_builder.run_async(text=text)

I also created a custom LLM class to ensure proper handling of the LLM response. Here’s the implementation of the class:
class CustomAnthropicLLM(AnthropicLLM):
    def invoke(self, input: str) -> str:
        try:
            logger.debug(f"Sending input to Anthropic API: {input[:500]}...")  # Logging first 500 characters
            response = self.client.messages.create(
                model=self.model_name,
                messages=[{"role": "user", "content": input}],
                **self.model_params,
            )
            logger.debug(f"Raw Anthropic API response: {response}")

            # Ensure the response content is processed correctly
            logger.debug(f"Response content type: {type(response.content)}")
            if isinstance(response.content, list):
                logger.debug(f"First element of response content: {response.content[0]}")

                # Concatenate TextBlock content into a single string
                content = " ".join(block.text for block in response.content if hasattr(block, "text"))
            elif isinstance(response.content, str):
                content = response.content
            else:
                raise ValueError(f"Unexpected response format: {response.content}")

            logger.debug(f"Processed LLM response: {content[:500]}...")  # Logging processed content
            return content
        except APIError as e:
            logger.error(f"Anthropic API Error: {e}")
            raise
        except Exception as ex:
            logger.error(f"Unexpected error during LLM invocation: {ex}")
            raise

The error seems to indicate that the text variable is expected to be a string but is instead being passed as a list.
Here is the method that initializes and runs the pipeline:
    async def define_and_run_pipeline(
    neo4j_driver: GraphDatabase.driver,
    llm: CustomAnthropicLLM,
    text: str
) -> PipelineResult:
    logger.info("Initializing SimpleKGPipeline...")
    try:
        # Make sure the text passed to the pipeline is a string and formatted correctly
        text = str(text)  # Ensure text is a string
        kg_builder = SimpleKGPipeline(
            llm=llm,
            driver=neo4j_driver,
            embedder=SentenceTransformerEmbeddings(),
            entities=["File", "Variable", "Paragraph", "Section"],
            relations=["CONTAINS", "USED_IN", "CALLS"],
            potential_schema=[ 
                ("File", "CONTAINS", "Section"),
                ("Section", "CONTAINS", "Paragraph"),
                ("Paragraph", "CONTAINS", "Variable"),
                ("File", "CALLS", "Paragraph"),
            ],
            from_pdf=False,
        )
        logger.info("SimpleKGPipeline initialized. Running pipeline...")
        logger.debug(f"Enriched text passed to pipeline: {text[:500]}...")  # Log first 500 characters of the text
        response = await kg_builder.run_async(text=text)
        logger.debug(f"Pipeline raw response type: {type(response)}, content: {response}")


        # Validate and debug response
        # logger.debug(f"Pipeline response: {response}")
        # return response

        # Ensure response is processed as string
        if isinstance(response, list):
            processed_response = " ".join([item.text for item in response if hasattr(item, "text")])
        elif isinstance(response, str):
            processed_response = response
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Unexpected response type: {type(response)}")

        logger.debug(f"Processed response: {processed_response[:500]}...")
        return processed_response
    
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error during pipeline execution: {e}")
        logger.error("Traceback: \n" + traceback.format_exc())
        raise

What I've tried:

Ensured the input text passed to run_async is explicitly converted to a string.

Verified that the response from the LLM is either a string or a list and handled both cases in the custom LLM class.


What I'm asking:

Why might response.content be a list instead of a string in this context?

Is there a better way to handle the LLM response to avoid this error?

Could the issue be in how SimpleKGPipeline processes the text input or in how the LLM API responds?


Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

define_and_run_pipeline seems to be passed a text value that is a list of TextBlocks.
Your code already has logic for extracting a string from a list of TextBlocks, and you can put that in a function:
def str_from_textblocks(block_list) -> str:
    return " ".join(block.text for block in block_list if hasattr(block, "text"))

Try replacing text = str(text) with text = str_from_textblocks(text).

Thank for your answer Cybersam
